# Unable to print the values of Date and String objects to the console in glassfish server

Tags: java, ejb, cdi

I have a CDI managed bean like this, which makes a call to print a Date type property of an Appointment object, I am calling `.toString()` on the Date object first and this prints with no problems:

```
    private String[] selectedApps;
    private List<String> appStrings;
    private List<Appointment> appointments;    

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        appointments = appointmentBean.getAppointments();
        appStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        appointments.forEach((n) -> {
            appStrings.add("START TIME: " + n.getStartTime().toString());
            System.out.print("APPOINTMENT TIME STRING: " + n.getStartTime().toString());
        });  
    }

    public String deleteApps() {
        if (selectedApps.length > 0) {
            appointmentBean.deleteAppointment(selectedApps);
            return "template.xhtml";
        } else {
            System.out.print("no apps selected");
            return "";
        }
    }
```

However, in an EJB I have another method, `deleteAppointment(String[] appStrings)`, which is trying to print these same values that have been passed to it from the `deleteApps()` method and it is unable to do so:

```
    public void deleteAppointment(String[] appStrings) {
        for (int i = 0; i < appStrings.length; i++) {
            String startStr = (appStrings[i].substring(12)).trim();
            System.out.print(startStr);
        }
    }
```

The only difference in the value that I am attempting to print from the CDI bean to the EJB, is that I have called the `.substring()` and `.trim()` methods on the string and if i don't use those methods and simply try to print the original string, then the print is successful. There are no errors or exceptions being thrown and no output of any kind to the console from the EJB method `deleteAppointments`. I have also been unable to find any solutions to this problem.

Thanks, Sam.

Comment: `There are no errors or exceptions being thrown and no output of any kind to the console` - It means the strings in `appStrings[]` are longer than 12 characters and the characters starting from index `12` are white spaces.

Comment: up until index 12 the strings all say "START TIME:", which can be seen in the init() method and after index 12 it is a time stamp, just in String type and not Date type.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Every string looks like this "START TIME: Tue Apr 07 17:38:00 BST 2020" or whatever date and time, but they are all in this format.

Comment: Put `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(appStrings))` as the first line in `deleteAppointment`. The output from this statement will give you hints on how to solve your problem. If you still need help, post the output of this statement and I'll look into it.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash the output from that line is this [START TIME: Tue Apr 07 17:38:00 BST 2020, START TIME: Wed Apr 08 12:17:00 BST 2020, START TIME: Thu Apr 09 17:33:00 BST 2020]|#], which is as expected.